# site is called twice?

Tags: php, google-chrome

My Problem is, that my php site is called twice.
But i don't know why. in my access-log i also get two entries if i reload:

```
127.0.0.12 - - [13/Oct/2010:20:41:56 +0200] "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1493 "http://mkw-testing/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.36 Safari/534.7"
127.0.0.12 - - [13/Oct/2010:20:41:57 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.36 Safari/534.7"
```

my error.log shows:

```
[Wed Oct 13 21:08:35 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.12] Zlib: Compressed 2766 to 1067 : URL /index.php
[Wed Oct 13 21:08:35 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.12] Zlib: Compressed 2743 to 1038 : URL /index.php/favicon.ico
```

what can i do? i don't have any redirects, reloads aso. in javascript code.

thx4help

might there be a problem with cookies?

shell i use htaccess file to be get the site is called only one time?

**UPDATE**

**independend of the acces log is my site obviously called twice!!** fact is, if i print out a index, which is incremented one point every call, the displayed site shows only odd numbers. so it makes a step of two instead of one. the increment function is NOT called twice in the code. and if i print the index to a textfile i get every number, not only the odd ones. .... i don't know what to do :-S, where to search, what to debug ....

here my html:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 
        <title>Testsuite</title> 

        <style type="text/css"> 
            ...

        </style> 

    </head> 
    <body> 
<!--script type="text/javascript">alert("go home!");</script--> 
<p style="font-size: smaller; color: #555"> 
Testcases ID: 75<br> 
Verbleibend: 94.5 % noch zu checken...<br> 
</p> 

<div id="action"> 
<h2>Suchprofile</h2> 
<p> 
    Screen number: B01 (4)<br> 
    Pfad: /search/type<br><br> 
</p> 
</div> 

<h2></h2> 

<form name="testsuite" action="/index.php" method="POST"> 
    <p style="width: 650px;"> 
        <span style="color: gray">Ausgangassituation:</span> Der User befindet sich auf der /search/type Seite. <br> 
        <span style="color: gray">Eingabe:</span> Der User klickt auf ?Dieses Suchprofil speichern?.         <br><br> 
        Reaktionen
        <input type="hidden" name="id_testcase" value="75" /> 
    </p> 
    <table width="650" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" > 
            <tr> 
            <td>Es &ouml;ffnet sich ein Eingabefeld </td> 
            <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="requirements[]" value="103" /></td> 
        </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td>Rechts neben dem Eingabefeld wird ein Plus-Symbol angezeigt.</td> 
            <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="requirements[]" value="104" /></td> 
        </tr> 
        </table> 

    <br> 
    <div style="border: 1px dashed #ccc; width: 650px; background-color: #ddd"> 
    <input type="radio" name="action" value="skip" id="skip" /><label for="skip">Ignorieren</label><br> 
    <input type="radio" name="action" value="store" id="store" checked/><label for="store">Speichern</label><br> 
    <br> 
    <center> 
        <input type="submit" id="submitter" value="weiter" /> 
    </center> 
    </div> 
</form> 




    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: WTF?? the phenomenon only occures in chrome.

Comment: Check if you are using adblock addon. I had the same problem and when I stopped addon problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this is one of Chrome's known quirks. It re-requests favicon.ico on every single page call (even view source!) Other browsers cache it. Nothing you need to be concerned about. Just make sure the file is there to avoid the 404 overhead! - by @chigley

**UPDATE**

after thinking about the **404 issue** i found an other resolution.

add this line into your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC]
```

---

*OLD and DEPRECATED*

hm to be able to accept an answer in this thread... I found a rather easy way to not react on that request ... **but it is for testreason only**

I just put this in the first php line of my index file:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/favicon.ico") return false;
```

even if the favicon.ico is there this will help you avoid double entries in your error-log files. it makes it much more readable then.

---

you have to know that i am using a `.htaccess` file like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC] 
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: @col. shrapnel ... better this way^^?

Answer (score 7):

Your site is called twice indeed, but your index page is only called once. The other request is looking for [favicon.ico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), i.e. the icon your browser will display in the tab/window your page resides in.

**EDIT:** @TokenMacGuy's comment below is probably right on the money.

Comment: okay but i print out a variable everytime index is called and get two entries each call ... ?? :-S

Comment: @helle - this is one of Chrome's known quirks. It re-requests favicon.ico on every single page call (even view source!) Other browsers cache it. Nothing you need to be concerned about. Just make sure the file is there to avoid the 404 overhead!

Comment: i don't know which part of the code to psot here. its aMVC architecture with many files. give me a hint where to search.

Comment: i do respect and honor this answere but it is not resolving the problem. pleas stop rating this answere. it leads to not reading the problem :-(

Comment: @helle, I understand my answer did not solve your problem, but if you don't provide us with the *server-side* code that implements your counter, as I asked you above, I'm afraid nobody will make any progress here :)

Answer (score 3):

That's totally normal, because that second second call is made to retrieve [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), a small icon which usually appears on a tab in the browser. Even if you don't have it, browsers will usually try to get it.

Answer (score 2):

the reason, why my index.php loaded, twice was another (so not the favicon): in my .htaccess I had my

```
ErrorDocument 404
```

command at the end of the file. putting it **before** the

```
RewriteEngine On
```

did the trick.

---

helle's answer led me to another helpful (quite simple) idea: to find out, which request is calling your index.php, simply put the following at the beginning of it:

```
file_put_contents('stats/stats.txt', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second call is the browser's attempt to get the favorites icon (favicon.ico).  Apparently you have one, since your server returned status 200, so not a problem.

Comment: it returned status 200 because the webserver interpreted GET /favicon.ico to call index.php with a path of index.php/favicon.ico.  That's pretty annoying!  there should probably be an actual favicon.ico file to fix it.

Comment: Probably a mod_rewrite hack to redirect everything non-physical (files/dirs) through index.php

Comment: the favicon is there ... hm. it's for an intern tool, so the problem has no priority to be solved anymore. we use firefox now instead of chrome...