# JQuery Ajax Form sends 2 email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Anyone knows why I receive 2 emails instead of 1???

I'm really new with JQuery and Ajax, in this code everything is working properly but is sending 2 email each time.

HTML

```html
<form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form">
  <fieldset>

    ...

    <!-- MENSAJE ENVIADO CON EXITO -->
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Tu mensaje se ha enviado con exito <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Gracias por contactar con nosotros, en breve responderemos tu mensaje.</div>

    <!-- BOTON SUBMIT -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12 derecha">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Enviar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({

      ...

    })
    var form = $('#contact_form'); // contact form

    // form submit event
    form.on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

        $.ajax({
            url: 'enviar.php', // form action url
            type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
            dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
            data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
            success: function(data) {
                $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow");
                $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

AND PHP

```php
<?php

if (!$_POST){ ?>
    <p>No se ha recibido ningún dato</p>
    <?php } else {

    ...

        if (mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, $headers)) {
            echo ("ok");
        };

    } ?>
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, use stack snippets if you have code that run in the browser js and html and all dependencies or 4 space indent for other code.

Comment: check the network tab for multiple requests

Comment: what is the code that executes for  $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm()

Comment: I think your PHP script is executing twice. This happens when request resource is not found in order to retrieve it. **e.g.**  favicon.ico Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4803067/4790490) post for more details.